# create a json file based on the array values

Tags: json

I have following array like

```
var Device = {
  'iPhone 6 Plus-Simulator-iOS 8.0': 'iPhone 6 Plus (8.0 Simulator)',
  'iPhone 6-Simulator-iOS 8.0': 'iPhone 6 (8.0 Simulator)',
  'iPhone 5s-Simulator-iOS 8.0': 'iPhone 5s (8.0 Simulator)',
  'iPhone 5s-Simulator-iOS 7.1': 'iPhone 5s (7.1 Simulator)',
  'iPhone 5s-Simulator-IOS 7.0.3': 'iPhone 5s (7.0.3 Simulator)',

};
```

i need to create a `json` file regarding the above information.
how can i possible to create `json` file with `key` and `value`

Answer (score 0):

You could create an object with the Key and Value parameters.

```
       public class Device
       {
       public Device(){}
       public string Key {get;set;}
       public string Value {get;set;}
       }

List<Device> deviceList = new List<Device>();
deviceList.Add(new Device() {Key = "", Value = "" } )
```

Then use a serializer to create a json file (for example Newtonsoft.JSON):

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deviceList);
```